# How to select a parent collection in 3d viewport?

Tags: selection-tools

Example: `ALT + G` on objects beneath each other, offers me to select one by displaying it's name.

Is there a similar function for collections? In particular I need to select parent collections from the 3d Viewport

e.g.

- ParentCollection

  - ChildCollection
  - ChildCollection_2

I need `Shift + G > Collection` **but for the parent collection**

Comment: Why not just do it in the outliner?

Comment: There is a Collection Manager Addon shipped with Blender but disabled by default which you can select collections in several ways. (Addons > Interface > Collection Manager)